# Why does a segment of code in java produce NaN when running?

Tags: java

So I'm running a segment of code (posted below and it produces a NaN when running (the code I'm running is just producing an answer that can be either negative or positive (quadratic basically)))

```
public double quadratic(int a, int b, int c)
{
  double quadratic = Math.pow(def, 2) - 4*def*def;
  return((-1*b + Math.sqrt(quadratic)) / 2*a);
 }
```

Comment: What is the input when you get NaN?

Comment: You get a NaN error when a non numerical value is passed into a method expecting a numerical value. what is the value type of def in your method?

Comment: what is this def reference, because you dont declare it here

Comment: `c` isn't used, is that expected?

Comment: @JosephOfem wrote: "You get a NaN error when a non numerical value is passed into a method expecting a numerical value. " - this is incorrect. javascript's parseInt works like this, java does not work like this. To get NaN in java, you need a number, and then you do an operation to it that has no result, such as trying to divide 0 by 0. (vs 0/1, which turns into Infinity).

Comment: *poor c is always ignored*

Answer (score 3):

The Math.sqrt(quadratic) returns a valid value only when quadratic is greater or equals to zero.

If quadratic is less than zero Math.sqrt(quadratic) returns NaN. For instance, it returns NaN if def is one.

Comment: To follow up a bit, this will __always__ be true. For every possible value of def. That reads: `quad = def * def - 4 * def * def`. In other words, that's `quad = -3 * def * def`, and `def*def` will be positive even if `def` is not (unless def is so large, and the type of 'def' is int or long, such that def*def overflows, then I don't know what happens).

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct formula. The discriminant is `b^2 - 4ac`. The first line of the method is equivalent to `def * def - 4 * def * def = -3 * def * def`, which produces a negative result in nearly all cases. `Math.sqrt` will return `NaN` when the argument is negative. This also means that the corrected method will still return `NaN` when the quadratic has no real roots.

```
public double quadratic(int a, int b, int c) {
  double quadratic = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  return((-1*b + Math.sqrt(quadratic)) / 2*a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following segment of code to make the NaN not appear anymore.

```
quadratic = (Math.pow(b, 2)) - 4*a*c;
quadratictwo = -1*b + (Math.sqrt(quadratic) / 2*a);
```

Comment: It's not producing the right value because it should be `return((-1*b + Math.sqrt(quadratic)) / 2*a);`